# Representing bars with different colors in matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

i have a bar graph having three bars as follows

```
x=[0.22,0.34,0.42]
bar(x,0.1,'stacked')
somenames={'IND Relation' ; 'DIS Relation' ; 'EQ Relation'}
set(gca,'xticklabel',somenames)
ylabel('F1')
```

all the three bars are in blue color but i want to represent `IND Relation` with Brown color, `DIS Relation` with green color and `EQ Relation` with blue color.

following is the output, i only want to change colors in above order `brown` `green` and `blue`

[image]

Comment: According to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99092-how-do-i-define-colors-for-individual-bars-on-my-bar-graph-according-to-their-values-in-matlab-7-1) there is no built in function to control the color of bars in a bar graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
x = [0.22,0.34,0.42];

h = figure;
a = axes('parent', h);
hold(a, 'on')

colors = {'r', 'b', 'g'};
somenames = {'IND Relation'; 'DIS Relation'; 'EQ Relation'}; 

for i = 1:numel(x)
    b = bar(i, x(i), 0.1, 'stacked', 'parent', a, 'facecolor', colors{i});
end

a.XTick = 1:3;
a.XTickLabel = somenames;

ylabel('F1')
```

[image]

Comment: ahhh color{i}, that's why, it can only assign color to each bar. I've been trying and getting errors in return

Comment: you are rite but on x axis i only want to write names of relations inplace of `1` `2` and `3`. for your assistance i have updated my question with sample output.

Comment: thanks for your answer this is exactly what i want but there is some warning at line `a.XTick = 1:3;` and  `a.XTickLabel = somenames;`, `Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double"`. output still shows `1` `2` and `3` instead of relation names.

Comment: Do you have another variable with the name `a`?

Comment: no i don't have any other `a` variable, i am using the exact code you mentioned above, with me in matlab `a` is `<1 cross 1>` struct

Comment: Well, then maybe it is related with your `Matlab` version. I'm using `R2015a` and no warning here.

Comment: If this is the answer to what you wnated, please consider acepting my answer. :)

Comment: @Afzaal Ahmad, instead of using `a.XTick = 1:3;` try `set(a,'XTick',1:3);` (and, similarily, `set(a, 'XTickLabel', somenames);`)